# Slicing up XAML when menus are large and complicated

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm porting a VB6-based editor to dotnet. It has a complex menu system. I'm noticing that as I build the menus in XAML, the file is getting longer and harder to navigate.

Is there a way of segmenting the XAML such that I can have the file menu in one XAML file, and the other top-level menus in their own separate XAML, all being included/combined at compile time?

[image: screenshot] A screenshot of the Google Sheets workbook I'm using to hold a dump of the menu. Some of it is dynamic but large parts are not. As you can see, it's quite complex and will have markup for icons as well.